# Assignment of a protected attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment, attr-accessible, attr-protected

I have a field on my User model that is protected because it determines clearance level. So it should be left protected and not mass-assignable. So even though attributes are protected by default in 3.2, that is actually the behavior I want.

However, on one controller method, I want to allow a manager to assign this field, for instance on user creation or user update.

**How do I allow the assignment of that attribute for specific controller actions?**

For example, I have my controller:

```
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
# ...
end
```

Now what I would do is exclude `clearance` from `params[:user]`, but it seems to get filtered out and raise and exception even before that line is reached (I tried putting a `debugger` right before that line and even comment it out, it still raised an exception).

**Where do protected attributes get caught, if not when calling `User#new`?**

Comment: Protected attributes should get caught before calling `User#new`, except when, like in my case, gem Cancan loads the resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Rails way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures) to do this would be to assign the attributes without protection or to use an admin role:

```
@user = User.new
@user.assign_attributes(params[:user], :without_protection => true)
@user.save
```

However, I found this to be a little tedious so I wrote a gem called [sudo_attributes](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes) that gives (in my opinion) a better API:

```
@user = User.sudo_new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

It mimics all of the Rails instantiation, creation, and updating methods (new, build, create, create!, update_attributes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I favored giving this kind of operation its own contained method, that only sets this value:

```rb
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

def full_clearance
  User.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:clearance, 'full')
end

def restricted_clearance
  User.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:clearance, 'restricted')
end
```

Now looking at [the Rails way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#countermeasures) Beerlington mentioned, I'd rather use roles, to give that particular action access to the clearance attribute:

```
# /app/models/user.rb

attr_accessible :attributes_accessible_by_default, ..., :clearance, :as => :manager

# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user].merge(:as => :manager)
# ...
end
```

In that case it's even possible, to give access based on a role attribute on the user:

```
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user].merge(:as => current_user.role.to_sym)
# ...
end
```

but that might lead to errors being raised again.